# how to reset datagridview using c#

Tags: c#

I am getting an error like System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot clear this list.'

Please help me to resolve this

```
        private void cmbServer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LicenseAllctnGridView.Rows.Clear();
        LicenseAllctnGridView.Columns.Clear();
        LicenseAllctnGridView.DataSource = objDBIO.ImportLicenseUsageDataFromDB(DBPath);          
        ((DataTable)LicenseAllctnGridView.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Server Like'{cmbServer.SelectedItem.ToString()}%'";
        this.LicenseAllctnGridView.Columns["Server"].Visible = false;
       // LicenseAllctnGridView.Rows.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting `DataSource` to `dataGridView` you can't clear rows of control. You can set `DataSource` to `null`.

**Or**,

```
((DataTable)LicenseAllctnGridView.DataSource).Rows.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `DataSource`  property to `null` instead of all the `Clear()` methods for your case.

```
LicenseAllctnGridView.DataSource = null;
```